Bottom navigation bar oversized
Bottom navigation bar is displayed incorrectly
Here is the code:
main_activity:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:itemIconSize="34dp"
            app:menu="@menu/menu">

        </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>

    </FrameLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

menu.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/main_navigation"
        android:title="@string/main_navigation_title"
        android:icon="@drawable/main_navigation_icon">
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/chats_navigation"
        android:title="@string/chats_navigation_title"
        android:icon="@drawable/chats_navigation_icon">
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/favorite_navigation"
        android:title="@string/favorite_navigation_title"
        android:icon="@drawable/favorite_naviagtion_icon">
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/main_profile"
        android:title="@string/profile_navifation_title"
        android:icon="@drawable/profile_navigation_icon">
    </item>

</menu>

Here's how it appears in the preview:
(https://i.sstatic.net/FX6KqTVo.png)
Here's how it shows up at startup on my phone:
(https://i.sstatic.net/cWWqiRBg.png)
I tried to make a fixed size, but it not only reduced the height of the navbar, but also cropped the text icons in the process.
